# iPhone EKEvent Availability, i try to set it, but it wont change

Tags: iphone, user-interface, sdk

Im trying to set the availability of an event i import into the iphone calendar with my app. Im using this code:

```
[event1 setAvailability:EKEventAvailabilityFree];
```

When i sync my iphone to my iCal i check the availability of the event, and it says "Busy". Xcode do ask for an integer, but there is none for the free option. I get no errors when i run this code, can someone please help figure out whats wrong.

Answer (score 9):

The problem is probably that the event's calendar hasn't been set.  When the calendar is not set, the event doesn't know if it's valid to set availability (not all calendars support availability).

Try the following:

```
EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
event.title = subject;
event.calendar = [eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents];
if (event.availability != EKEventAvailabilityNotSupported) {
    event.availability = EKEventAvailabilityFree;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Further to [David Hunt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960397/iphone-ekevent-availability-i-try-to-set-it-but-it-wont-change/8696615#answer-7314007) it would appear that you need to set the calendar *before* you set the availability in your code. The sequence matters.

E.g.

```
event.calendar = //calendar object
event.availability = //availability typedef
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you save the event back to the event store that contains it? See the `saveEvent:span:error:` message in the [EKEventStore class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKEventStoreClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/EKEventStore).

Comment: Yes I obviously do that when im able to sync my apps events from the Calendar.app into iCal. The problem is that it isnt free, its busy. Btw I use the defaultCalendarForNewEvents, is that the problem. If so, can someone show me how I can customize a custom calendar?